# Transformed elements do not respect absolute position on Firefox when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have spent quite some time on this one and can't seem to find a way around it. I am trying to create a table with a fixed header that can scroll both horizontally and vertically. However, I have stumbled upon a really strange bug I can't explain.

The idea is simple. A table lies inside a `scrollable` parent, which lies inside an absolutely positioned `container`. The table header labels are placed inside `span` elements and absolutely positioned at the top. When the `scrollable` element is scrolled, using Javascript the `span` elements are moved using css transforms. Below is a sample code of the code used.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span>Column 1</span></th>
          ...
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Table cell content</td>
          ...
       </tr>  
    </table>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
  scrollX=$(this).scrollLeft();
  $(this).find('th span').attr('style', 'transform:translateX(' + -scrollX + 'px)');
})
```

Here is a fiddle of the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rts4gd5x/

The code works correctly and as it should in all browsers I tested (ie11, ie edge, chrome, safari) but in Firefox only I am encountering the following issue.

If you scroll the `scrollable` element and then resize the window, the position of the `span` elements misbehaves and I can't pinpoint what's bothering it. Resizing from zero scroll and then scrolling works as it should.

I have tried everything I could think of, adding `transform:translateZ(0)` to the parents, adding `min-width`, etc, but no hack I tried works. Using `fixed` positioning on the `span` elements could be adjusted to work on this simplified layout, but the actual layout I am working on requires `absolute` positioning for the spans. Every other browser this solution is tested on works as expected.

Comment: Might be a bug in Firefox. Since people most likely won't playing around with resizing, the problem is not that big. An easy fix is to hook up on the resize event and simply redraw the scroll postition

Comment: @LGSon how would you redraw? In order not to look weird some kind of action would have to take place when beginning the resize. The strange thing is that if you scroll, resize and refresh, it is in place :/

Comment: Did a few tests forcing a redraw, with no luck, so I came up with another way, which I posted for you

Answer (score 1):

Ok this question had me intrigued, so i went ahead and tried to hack it out to make it work for this particular scenario. After looking at how multiple properties of the  elements change on resize, i found one that could be manipulated for a fix(hack). If you take a look at the offset coordinates of the table headers, you'll notice that upon resize, (only in firefox) the left offset property is decremented by the amount of the scroll. So if the `scrollX` value is `50` and the left offset of the first th element is at `-120`, then after resize, the value of the left offset becomes `-170`. This is what causes the misalignment.

So the fix is to keep track of the offset of the first `th` element while scrolling. Then within the `$(window).resize()` function; you use this last recorded value of the offset and compare it to the current offset. If its not the same (within some margin of error, I used 1px as this margin, seems to work) then go through all the `th` elements and update the offsets to their previous value , which is their current value + the `scrollX` value.

An interesting thing is that this offset misalignment only occurs on the first resize. So using the example above; after it becomes `170` any subsequent resizing wont keep adding `50` to the value, it'll remain at `170`. This means that this fix only has to be applied once. This is why that check with the margin of error is in there. Since this offset problem doesn't occur in chrome for example, the check will also make sure not to impact any rendering there.

Additionally, I noticed that there was an issue using `item.attr('style', 'transform...')`, where after the resize fix was implemented, re-scrolling would cause another misalignment. Fortunately using `item.css('transform',...)` fixed that problem.

Take a look at the code:

```
let scrollX = 0;
let lastOffset = $('.scrollable').find('th span').first().offset();
$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
    scrollX=$(this).scrollLeft();
    let thList = $('.scrollable').find('th span')
    thList.css('transform', 'translateX(' + -scrollX + 'px)');
    lastOffset = thList.first().offset();
})

$(window).resize(function(){
  //If scrollable hasnt moved, no need to make any changes
  if(scrollX == 0){
        return;
  }
  let thList = $('.scrollable').find('th span');
  let currentLeftOffset = Math.abs(thList.first().offset().left);
  //Check if currentLeftOffset is withing a margin of error
  //of last left offset, it it is, no need to proceed with the
  //updating th offsets
  if((currentLeftOffset - Math.abs(lastOffset.left)) < 1 ){
    return;
  }
  //Iterate through all th elements and apply the offset adjustment
  thList.each(function(itm){
        let offset = $(this).offset();
    offset.left = offset.left + scrollX; 
    $(this).offset(offset);
  });
});
```

Updated **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rts4gd5x/4/)**

Comment: Interesting findings - especially that it only occurs once. I think it only happens once because after the js runs once it gets a `left` value, so it is properly positioned horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a couple of ways to do a *refresh* on resize, but with no luck, so here is another option, where I use `margin-left` instead.

Again, Firefox behave differently than the rest, so with a simple browser detect (sorry for that one, used it for this demo only, recommend to do this in a more proper way) I got it working

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/rts4gd5x/11/)

```js
$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
 scrollX=$(this).scrollLeft();
 
 // Firefox
 if (!(window.mozInnerScreenX == null)) {
   $(this).find('thead').attr('style', 'margin-left: ' + -scrollX + 'px');
   
 // the rest
 } else { 
   $(this).find('th span').attr('style', 'margin-left: ' + -scrollX + 'px');
 }
})
```

```css
.container {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
  left:20px;
  height:200px;
  padding-top:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.scrollable {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
  background:white;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  text-align:left;
}
table th span {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  border-left:1px solid #ccc;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  line-height:40px;
  background:#fff;
  margin-left:-1px;
}

table td {
  white-space:nowrap;
  border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="scrollable">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><span>Column 1</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 2</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 3</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 4</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 5</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 6</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 7</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 8</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 9</span></th>
    <th><span>Column 10</span></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
    <td>Table cell content</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @LGSon! Looks like your code is a lot slimmer and works well. However, I wish there was some kind of value to avoid using extra js altogether and keep GPU accelerated css3 transforms only. I'll just wait a bit longer and see if a css only solution turns up.

Comment: @scooterlord There is no proper CSS only solution that work with both vertical and horizontal scroll (yet), ...well, CSS Grid might do it, though has limited browser support. So today you'll need JS. Since HTML Table is one of the most none cross browser elements out there, when you try to pull of stuff like relative/absolute positions and transform, a better approach would most likely be to use standard div, as they will not misbehave in the same way. If CSS Flexbox is an option, it will simplify the code a little and make it more maintainable.

Comment: @scooterlord Also, even if GPU accelerated transforms is good, it has little, if at all, impact when it comes to do a simple thing as move an element during a scroll.

Comment: Flexbox has still limited support according to my own standards and for the specific project `colspans` and `rowspans` are required so I can't use `divs` either. :/

Comment: @scooterlord Then I know for a fact, that I posted a good solution for you :)

Comment: I am surprised that this only works on FF. If margin offset was working on other browsers I would completely replace the transforms. Also, not a matter of this topic but FF52 and the way its scroll event fires has already caused a lot of issues :/

Comment: @scooterlord When it comes to the good old `table` element, there is many things that work in one browser and not the others, and the other way around.